# Вычислить радиус круга yandex maps

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Я хочу сделать так в яндекс картах
1) Пользователю в центре карты показывается круг (как метка, через css) фиксированного размера 
2) Вычисляется радиус круга в метрах
3) Радиус зависит от зума, который выбрал пользователь. То есть чем больше зум тем больше радиус, т.к большая площадь карты попадает в круг.

Скажите, пожалуйста как это сделать? 
Подобная разработка есть у сервиса hh.ru в их приложении под Android, она работает при поиске работы.

Возможно можно поставить задачу по другому
1) Рассчитать расстояние от центра карты до, например, правой стороны ее div`a, т.к если мы показываем карту в квадрате то не важно до какой стороны брать радиус. При этом расстояние радиуса должно зависеть от текущего zoom

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92027/discussion-on-question-by-masquitos----yandex-maps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно вычислить по формуле взятой из википедии, но если не хотим эту формулу искать, то:

```
var polyline, circle;
// Отрисовать круг с радиусом, вывести радиус в консоль.
    function drawCircle(){
// Удаляем круг и линию (можно менять их координаты если хочется)
        myMap.geoObjects.remove(polyline).remove(circle);
// находим центр карты и координаты её углов
        var bounds = myMap.getBounds();
        var center = myMap.getCenter();
// получаем точку лежащую справа по центру
        var rightPoint = [center[0], bounds[1][1]];
// добавляем линию с координатами центра и правой центральной точки
        polyline = new ymaps.Polyline([center, rightPoint]);
        myMap.geoObjects.add(polyline);
// высчитываем её длину
        var distance = polyline.geometry.getDistance();
// выводим её в консоль
        console.log(distance);
// добавляем круг на карту, с центром в центре карты и радиусом найденным ранее
        circle = new ymaps.Circle([center,distance]);
        myMap.geoObjects.add(circle);
    }
// подписываемся на событие изменения размеров карты
    myMap.events.add('boundschange', drawCircle);
// отрисовываем круг при отрисовке карты
    drawCircle();
```

Как правильно указывают выше, это будет хорошо работать для карты с большими зумами. Но если отзумиться на весь мир, то начнутся проблемы. 
https://jsfiddle.net/afsmt9Lx/

Comment: а почему справа? возьмите сверху и дисторшен по горизонтали не будет влиять, искажения же только по горизонтали? или какая там прокция у карт яндекса? я ничего не могу нормально с телефона посмотреть сейчас

Comment: Справа, потому, что пользователь написал "расстояние от центра карты до правой стороны"

Comment: ну он не знал особенностей географических проекций, и сказал наобум, я полагаю

Comment: Либо ему нужен был код от которого оттолкнуться и написать, то что он хочет. Или код который работает допустимо хорошо на зумах когда видны только дома и улицы.

Comment: @se0ga дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на вики

Comment: @StrangerintheQ правую сторону указал на угад

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Comment: @se0ga Мне кажется вашего кода достаточно, спасибо!

Comment: @Stranger in the Q "а почему справа? возьмите сверху и дисторшен по горизонтали не будет влиять" - скажите - это какая координата bounds[0][1]?

Comment: @pepel_xD Вероятно это не ко мне

Comment: @Stranger in the Q разве самый верхний комментарий не Вы писали?

Comment: @pepel_xD Вы приводите фрагмент кода из ответа